# Is there a good reference to learn about Castelnuovo-Mumford regularity?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I am asking for maybe some lecture notes or a book giving a modern treatment to the topic. My background is Hartshorne chapters 2,3,4. Thank you in advance

Comment: This is treated early on in volume 1 of Lazarsfeld's *Positivity in Algebraic Geometry*. It's not tremendously detailed, but there should be some references at least.

Comment: Mumford's Curves on a surface has a very detailed proof of this.

Comment: You may refer to this self-contained note http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/bcp/bcp36/bcp36111.pdf

Comment: Thank you all for the references. That is exactly what I was looking for